# ODE ‎Phase portraits of 2x2 systems.‎

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Soving a linear 2 by 2 systems yeilds two eigenvector $λ_1= 0$, $λ_2\lt 0$. In this case, do we say the origin is a stable node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are calling a stable node.

Often, stable means that if a solution starts nearby it stays nearby. This is the case here.

Asymptotically stable means that if a solution starts nearby it will tend to the equilibrium. That is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Let A = the 2x2 matrix the represents this linear system and let T = the trace of A.  If det(A) > 0 and
$T^2 - 4det(A) >= 0$ then there is a node at the origin.  The node is stable if T<0.